# How to design flexible appbar like this

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-animation

[image: It will be shown when app start]

[image: When scrolling then app bar will be shown like this]

How to design like this in flutter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try to use SliverAppBar and TabBar!